# Kibana count unique records based on log value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

I want to create a Kibana `metric` for the unique users visiting my site.
I have an index collecting logs from a service in format

`<date> <user1@gmail.com> - <log message> <client>`

and I want to count unique user emails ignoring the rest of the fields.

Is it possible to do such a regex via some of the aggregations? Currently I was able to find only unique count based on some specific field which is not an option for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate field first:

1. Either by using kibana scripted fields.
2. Or by using logstash mutate filter plugin.

And then you can apply terms aggregation on data table visualization to achieve this.